# "Hiding" Facebook 'Like' button if user has already liked the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I know this question has already come up and I know that it's against FB policy to obscure/cover the social plugin. What I'm really looking for is any kind of solution to the very legitimate problem of users accidentally unliking pages because the button was poorly designed.

Our team recently noticed some peculiar patterns with our FB page likes and unlikes. After investigating, we've come to the conclusion that many users who already liked our FB page are hitting the Like button on our webpage, not realizing that this is causing them to unlike the page.

The obvious solution is to detect if the user has already liked our FB page and hide the plugin if it's true but this is not allowed by FB policy. So what can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: As you said it is not allowed to do like gating.

Comment: I am not trying to trying to do any kind of like gating. I am trying to figure out how to stop users from inadvertently unliking my page because FB's like button provides confusing visual feedback.

Comment: There is no way.